# Find number of records in a date range

Tags: mysql

table : booked_timings

```
    id     | from date             |     todate          | vehicle id
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
   1        2017-05-04 06:00:00      2017-05-04 08:00:00     98
   2        2017-05-04 10:00:00      2017-05-04 12:00:00     98
   3        2017-05-04 15:00:00      2017-05-04 18:30:00     98
```

Above table consists of the booked timings of vehicle with id 98. I need an MySQL query to list out all the booked timings for vehicle with id 98 when user tries to book in following timings

(i) 08:00:00 to 12:00:00 
(ii) 05:00:00 to 23:00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 1=1 AND 
(
    (
        STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(FROMDATE,'%H:%i:%s'),'%H:%i:%s') > STR_TO_DATE(08:00:00,'%H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(FROMDATE,'%H:%i:%s'),'%H:%i:%s') < STR_TO_DATE(12:00:00,'%H:%i:%s')
    )
    OR
    (
        STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(FROMDATE,'%H:%i:%s'),'%H:%i:%s') > STR_TO_DATE(05:00:00,'%H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(FROMDATE,'%H:%i:%s'),'%H:%i:%s') < STR_TO_DATE(23:00:00,'%H:%i:%s')
    )
)
```

As shown in above code,assuming that `fromdate` and `todate` are COLUMN with `DATE` datatype.And comparing only time fraction of that column with time duration which specified by you.Again here we provide string,so we need to convert this string to date using

`STR_TO_DATE()`function.

Try above code,hope this will helps.